# How to find city based on current location lat, lng without reverse geocoding?

Tags: node.js, geojson, kml, shapefile, qgis

How to find city based on current location lat, lng without reverse Geo coding ? I tried to save Indian cities data in the form of Geo json but it is of type Multi Polygon. i didn't find any way to convert it to single polygon which is easy to find. if i try to find lat lng inside every polygon it will take lot of time. i want to do it efficiently and faster way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use an API, you will need to maintain a list of cities and their coordinates yourself. 
For example, here is a good starting point for such a list:
 https://www.latlong.net/category/cities-102-15.html

With the list, take current lat/lng and calculate the distance. [Euclidian distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) would work well enough for most practical applications. Sort the results starting by smallest and take the first one. This is your nearest city.

Comment: Thanks for replying and i thought about it first but there are some cases like city A has more diameter then city B and i am standing at the edge of city A. In that case i am still in city A but by this rule i'll be in city B. is there any way to avoid or reduce such edge cases ?

Comment: Knowing if you are inside the city limits complicates the whole problem. You could use Open Streetmap API to fetch city boundaries (https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/68298/extract-polygon-data-of-city-boundaries).  Then, check if you are inside or outside a city. However, there are a number of edge cases (i.e. city within a larger city) which makes it a complex problem There is a reason why geolocation APIs exit.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this is exactly what i was looking for polygon of city.